# Android Google Maps Web Services (Navigation)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

According to google maps license, using MapView in android commercial application is free, as long as you avoid following:

> The Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service only apply if you 
>   use any of the JS/Flash/Static Maps APIs or Maps API Web Services (the 
>   REST based interfaces) in your Android application.

If my application was free to download for anyone from android market (and thus "publicly available"), can i also use Web Services in commercial application (developed for paying client, but then published to android market and free to install)

Your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Maps API licensing](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)

[Free, Public Accessibility to Your Maps API Implementation](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1)

Comment: Not exactly the answer i expected, but it helped me.